# RVM $PATH variables to homeless user

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, rvm, compass-sass

I have a staging server running Ubuntu 12.04 and I'm creating some post-receive scripts on git to automate deployment of some repositories we keep on that server.

I created a homeless user 'git' (for security reasons) to deal git's ssh connections.

I want to run `compass compile` (compass is installed as a ruby gem) when somebody pushes something on the repo.
So I used RVM to install and manage ruby on that server. 
And I did all rvm installation process using the multi-user approach.
When I run ruby -v with the 'git' user, I get the right output, I mean, rvm multi-user instalation is almost ok.

The problem is when I try to run an executable gem.

I noticed my normal user's .bash_profile had this (added by rvm):

```
[[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

This code add gems' bin directory to the $PATH.

```
[normaluser]$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/:/usr/local/rvm/bin
```

As 'git' user is homeless it doesn't have a .bash_profile so I added that code to a script on /etc/profile.d/

But it didn't worked because every time I try to execute /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm as git, it  exit's the git's bash session and return to my normal user session. It goes something like:

```
[normaluser]$ sudo -u git bash
[git]$ exec /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm
[normaluser]$
```

No erros are printed...

**Why is rvm script exiting from bash session?**

**How can I set rvm $PATH on a homeless user?**

Comment: Why are you running `exec`? That's what exec does. It will replace the currently running process (in this case the shell), with the command you give it. Once the command finishes there is no shell to return to.

Comment: hmmm... that was my ignorance. I didn't know exec behaved like that. I changed #!/bin/sh to #!/bin/bash and used source instead of exec. Now I'll executing /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm inside my post-receive script and ensure that the path variable are set properly... thank you very much, the first question is solved and it helps me to go further.

Answer (score 0):

three issues:

1. you should not use `/bin/sh` it is not supported by RVM, use `/bin/bash` instead (but you got it already
2. as explained by @Casper => exec replaces current shell with the command you run, there is no return
3. there are docs describing how to use RVM in `init.d` => https://rvm.io/integration/init-d

you should not try to source rvm for the user in shell initialization files as they are not used by init.d scripts, use wrappers instead, it's the most proven way to make it work.